# Bad behavior of block?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, i have an instance variable _poze which is a NSMutableArray.I have the following code in which i add objects to my array _poze:

```
for(int i=0;i<[picIDs count];i++){
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",picIDs[i]];
    FBRequest *fbr = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:picIDs[i] parameters:nil HTTPMedthod:nil];
    [fbr startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError* error){
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        [_poze addObject:[result valueForKeyPath:@"cover.source"]];
    }];
}
```

The problem with this is that even if i get the result from the block, the array adds objects but immediately after it exits that block my _poze array will show 0 objects again.Any reason why this happens?

Comment: Where did you check your _poze array? Directly after the block? The code within the block isn't executed necessarily before the code following the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FBRequest` completion handler is called asynchronously with respect to the call to `startWithCompletionHandler`.  The completion handler block is called when the actual network request completes.  Since you're creating a bunch of requests in a tight loop, you're just queuing them up.  They won't even start until the for loop exits and the stack unwinds.

`_poze` will start to get populated with the results as the requests complete, in whatever order they complete.

Comment: Thats it, thanks, and do you have any idea how to get the actual results? set the block to execute on the main thread? even though that would affect performance i guess.

Comment: That's what the completionBlock is there for. You didn't do anything other than adding something to an array. Anything else you need to process the new data you call from that completion block.